# C definition of: static void (*var_name)();

Tags: c, methods

I download a code example written in C, but don't understand one instruction. And besides, w
hen i try to compile the code the compiler throws me an error just in the line that i don't understand.

Code:

```
// Global vars
static int getting_text = 0;
static char *the_text;  // Definition Part
static void (*text_entered)();  // Definition Part 2


// method
int add_text(unsigned char key)
{
  char msg[] = "x";
  int len;

  if(!getting_text) return 0;
  if(key==8) /* backspace */
  {
    len = strlen(the_text);
    the_text[len-1] = '\0';
  }
  else if(key==13 || key==9) // cr or tab ends
  {
    getting_text = 0;
    text_entered(the_text); // Execution Part
  }
  else
  {
    msg[0] = key;
    strcat(the_text, msg);
  }

  glutPostRedisplay();

  return 1;
}
```

The compiler throws me an error about there are too many arguments in the method's calling. But i don't if it's a method the static void (*xxx)() or if other thing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't add asterisks to indicate sections of interest. Use something like `// comment` next to the lines to show what the problem is

Comment: Did you really use a C compiler? Or did you use a C++ compiler?

Comment: I use first a C++ compiler and after that I try with the C compiler. But i think the best option to compile the code is use the C++ one.

Comment: @JorgeVegaSánchez: No, the best option is to use a C compiler because this is valid C code. It compiles with `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic` (admittedly with warnings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: The following only applies to C++. Did you use g++ or some other C++ compiler instead of a C compiler?

text_entered is a function pointer to a function that doesn't take any arguments, hence the error, because you're passing it a character pointer. I assume it should change to,

```
static void (*text_entered)(char*);
```

This is of course assuming text_enterered actually gets set to a function that takes a char* argument and it isn't just being called wrong.

Comment: No, it's not. It's a function pointer to a function that takes any arguments. In C. That's why I asked about C++ - there it's is a function pointer to a function that doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: Oops, Sebastian appears to be correct. Edited post to note that it's only valid if he used a C++ compiler instead of a C one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Know works fine and i understand what the function do.